# Is pink salmon the same as Alaskan?

Tags: fish, salmon

I'm new to salmon. I've been trying new dishes but I read online that Alaskan salmon is not the greatest. But is pink salmon the same as Alaskan salmon?

I've been using chicken of the sea pink salmon wild caught, for quick dishes like sandwiches or salad etc..

Just wanted to make sure I'm eating the right kind. Any suggestions for canned/pouched salmon are welcome.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the alaskan salmon package? Is there any information, maybe a QR-code, indicating where the fish came from?

Answer (score 3):

I live in the Pacific Northwest, so I know quite a bit about salmon.  You have to, or they exile you.

First, I have no idea why you'd think that Alaskan salmon is bad. Given their extensive river networks and vast areas of untouched wilderness, Alaskans catch some of the best salmon in the world.  The salmon that is categorically inferior is [farmed salmon](https://www.mashed.com/146396/the-truth-about-farmed-salmon-vs-wild-salmon/), or salmon that's raised in a pen.  Now, farmed salmon tends to have a lighter, "pink" color to it compared with wild-caught, so I can see how you might get confused between that and Pink Salmon.

[Pink Salmon](https://www.fisheries.noaa.gov/species/pink-salmon) is a specific species of salmon.  It's not considered as desireable as Coho, Chinook, King, or Sockeye, mostly because the shorter lifespan of the Pink Salmon means that it has a less well-developed flavor.  However, its short lifespan also means that it bounces back quickly from fishing, and as a result is the most sustainable and ecologically responsible salmon to eat.  They catch a lot of Pink Salmon in Alaska, but it's also available from Canada, Washington, Oregon, and Russia.

And ... since you're using *commercially canned* salmon, you're really not going to taste a lot of difference between salmon varieties anyway.

If you want to try a little better quality canned salmon, I'd suggest any of these brands: Wild Planet, Crown Prince Natural, or North Pacific Seafood (although, to be fair, Chicken of the Sea isn't bad).  You can also splurge and order from a tiny specialty place like [Totem SmokeHouse](https://www.totemsmokehouse.com/product-page/3-3-oz-cooked-trio-salmon-combination).  You can also try Canned Red Salmon, which is generally Sockeye, and has a different flavor.

Comment: Is the OP maybe referring to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_pollock

Comment: Maybe?  What's wrong with Alaska Pollock, though?

Comment: Nothing wrong at all. It would take the question in another direction.

Comment: King and [chinook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinook_salmon) are the same fish - you're banished from the land!  Seriously though, the fifth PNW salmon is chum.  So, all five are chinook/king, coho/silver, sockeye/red, chum/dog, pink/humpback.  And we might add steelhead to the list, though I don't remember ever seeing it canned.

Comment: I've seen it canned, but only from really small local producers.

Answer (score 1):

Canned pink salmon is often from the Pacific North West.  [Here is some info on pink salmon.](https://www.adfg.alaska.gov/index.cfm?adfg=pinksalmon.printerfriendly)  You can also go to the [Chicken of the Sea website](https://chickenofthesea.com/products/salmon/) to see what they say.
That's about as much help as we can provide given your question.  We are not a suggestion or recipe sharing site.

Comment: Er, where did the OP ask for recipes?

Comment: @FuzzyChef how do you interpret the last line of the question?

Comment: Looking for advice on brands and types.  That's who I answered it, anyway.

Comment: @FuzzyChef...fair point, I see that...but clearly not how I interpreted it.